# Training reconstruction errors higher than test reconstruction errors

Tags: deep-learning, loss-function, autoencoder, anomaly-detection

I have a dataset of 100.000 raws and 14 columns containing 5% of anomalies in its tail, i'm trying to detect these anomalies by using an autoencoder. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlbTL.png)
I trained the model on the normal data only, when i plotted the distributions of reconstruction errors for both training and testing data i realized that the errors on the testset are lower than the trainset [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62PLa.png). Knowing that i have binary nested classes [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6dnX.png) and i normalized the data with MinMax, can this has an impact on the errors i'm getting or the model is not appropriate for this task?

Comment: How exactly did you normalize the data? You should normalise on train, and the apply the transformation directly on test.

Comment: How are you checking that the autoencoder is correct? Do you use a validation set?

Comment: How was train and testing data split?

Comment: When plotting distributions to compare them the X axis should be the same. And ideally plot them into the same axis. Can use KDE lineplot if histograms get too messy

Comment: Yes, i fit normalization on train then transform on train and test. For the validation i'm using 25% of train, and i have 5000 rows for test which are anomalies